# Does Junos convert routing policy into binary tree?

Tags: juniper, juniper-mx

Let's say, that there is a following simply route policy in Juniper router:

```
root@vmx> show policy test
Policy test:
    Term 1:
        from
             route filter:
                 10.10.10.7/32 exact
                 192.168.10.0/24 orlonger
        then accept
    Term 2:
        then reject

root@vmx>
```

How does Junos validate routes against this route policy internally? Does it convert it into a binary tree data structure and checks the routes against it in the control plane?

Comment: Can you provide any additional context around the question?  Policy is a pretty hefty topic and I'd like to be as specific as possible.

Comment: I was simply wondering, how does Junos check routes against a route policy internally. Does it read in each route policy and build a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) for each policy and check routes from the RIB against that binary tree if the policy is applied in export direction under protocol configuration?